# want to hide/modify my link in address bar while opening a link in web browser using java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to open a link in web browser using java swing but for security reasons I dont want the user to see the link. So I wish hide the address bar or modify the link so that the user cannot use the link in negative ways. How do I do it?

My code:

```
URI uri = null;

uri = new URI("my.original.link");

Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

Now how do I hide the link/address bar or modify the original link to some false value so that it is useless to user?

Comment: *"so that it is useless to user"* 1) Don't do that. It's horrible. 2) It is not possible in pure Java. 3) Just don't do that.

Comment: The web browser will always be able to see the link, otherwise it won't be able to open it. The user will always be able to see this link too, if he wants to (using network debugging tools either inside the browser or 3rd party). Don't base your security on hiding the URL.

Comment: You should try to tell us why you want to hide the URL, because if you want to hide some `GET` data then maybe you should `POST` it instead, not that it reliably hides it but the normal end-user is going to have a harder time to retrieve it. Also, if you just want to display the information on a page then you can always just download the page and display what you downloaded (not that it would be particularly easy to do it with most pages nowadays relying so hard on asynchronous JS loads). If it's for security reasons then maybe you should use secure channels to transmit sensitive information.

Comment: i just dont want the user to use the link in any wrong way. for example the can modified some values in the link and view someone else's data.

Answer (score 1):

You're not able to do that with the Desktop.browse() method. The URL will be visible to the user.

You could perform a server side redirect afterwards, but the user would still see the original URL for a short time at least.